# How to send user input to reset system idle time in C#?

Tags: c#, macos, mono

I want to reset the system idle time with my application.
On windows I can do this with [SendInput](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.sendinput).
Question is how can I do this on OSX?

Thanks for the help!

EDIT 1:
I also tried UpdateSystemActivity without success, where IdleTime idleSeconds gives back the HIDIdleTime.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{  
     while (true) {  
          NSLog(@"Idle seconds: %lu", (unsigned long)[[IdleTime sharedIdleTime] idleSeconds]);  
          [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1];  
     }  
});  
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{  
     while (true) {  
          dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{  
             UpdateSystemActivity(OverallAct);  
          });  
          [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:5];  
     }  
});
```

EDIT 2:
I also tried to reset the idle time by this [article](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1340/_index.html) (listing 2) with every possible paramter of kIOPMAssertionType. Unfortunately without success..
Again: I want a solution in c# but I just wanted to see wether it is possible with another language.

Answer (score 1):

On OSX you can use P/Invoke as well. The function to be executed is named UpdateSystemActivity. Here's the [example](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1160/_index.html). The signature will probably be:

```
[DllImport ("/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/CoreServices")]
private extern static void UpdateSystemActivity(byte activity);
```

Comment: It seems that this has been deprecated.

Comment: @Bence: I see. That's unlucky, but that was the only method I've known :/ I will remove the answer.

Comment: @konrad-kruczynski: I think that your answer with my comments will be useful for others. Anyway thank you for your answer!

Comment: Ok, I'll leave it then.